# SpringBoot method that saves users is setting lastname as null

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new at using SpringBoot (this is my first project) and I'm trying to create a simple controller to save users with a post method that requires a JSON RequestBody that also returns a JSON containing the same user as a response. The method seems to work well, I'm gettig a JSON back when I make the post request but for some reason the lastName of the User is always null, as you can see in the image.

[Post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeIC0.png)

(I've used lombok to create getters, setters and constructors)

My User entity is pretty simple:

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long userId;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;

}
```

And this is the UserController:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;


import com.example.demo.entity.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @PostMapping("/")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User u) {
        log.info(u.toString());
        return userService.saveUser(u);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }
}
```

I supposed this is a dumb question but haven't found any similar post with a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not controller.

Comment: Yo're right. My bad!

Comment: Next time, instead of images, paste request and response

Comment: @Antoniossss Okay! Thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in your body

`"lastName:":"xxx"` see extra `:` as a field name?? So your field is named `lastName:` which obviously does not exist in `User` thus null.

Comment: Why isn't it throwing? Shouldn't it look for a field with that illegal name?

Comment: Thanks so much! I had the problem right in front of me and couldn't see it. I feel pretty dumb right now :)

Comment: @Velerij depends on jackson settings. It can ignore unknown fields on throw exception

Comment: @VaroVárez cibsuder acceoting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Request contain a typo error as `"lastName:":`? remove the extra colon `":"` used in the `"lastName"`.In your postman pass as `"lastName":"XXX"`.

Comment: This is exact the same answer